# How to display a KML (or GPX?) file on a Nativescript Angular app?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to make an app using Nativescript-Angular that displays a route on a map like this : https://prnt.sc/10cy40s using .kml or .gpx files that I upload online somewhere else.

But I can't find anything regarding this with Nativescript-Angular or maybe I'm not asking the right questions ^^'

Thanks in advance !

Edit : To be more clear, I'm not expecting a magic answer, but more of a guidance about what I missed during my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native KML support in the google-maps-sdk plugin, but what I did was extract the coordinates and create a polyline.  This has worked well for me.

Comment: Hi David,
thanks a lot, I'll try this out !

Have a nice evening :D